# Blazor Custom Compare Attribute Validation - Secondary Validation fails

Tags: c#, validation, blazor

I have a Blazor application with a dat entry page.

I am trying to make a custom validation rule that makes it mandatory: IF checkbox(type_other) is checked, then textbox(OtherIncidentType) becomes mandagtory.

The first part is working properly with the custom Compare Below:

HTML

```
<DataAnnotationsValidator />
<ValidationSummary />
<RadzenLabel Text="Other. "/>
<RadzenCheckBox @bind-value=@WIR40Entity.type_other />
<RadzenLabel Text="If Other, please describe: " />
<RadzenTextbox @bind-value=@WIR40Entity.OtherIncidentType />
```

CumstomCompareAttributes Class

```
public class CustomCompareAttributesOther : CompareAttribute
public CustomCompareAttributesOther(string otherProperty) : base(otherProperty)
{}
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
WIR40 entity = (WIR40)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
if (entity.type_other == true && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entity.OtherIncidentType))
{ return new ValidationResult("When selecting Other as an Incident, a Description is also needed.");}
return ValidationResult.Success;
}
}
```

Model

```
[CustomCompareAttributesOther(name(OtherIncidentType))]
public bool? type_other {get; set;}
public string? OtherIncidentType {get; set;}
```

Right now, it is working 50%

If a user checks the checkbox, the Validation Message Displays (reminding them to enter a Description).

Problem is that AFTER the user enters the description in the proper text box, the error still displays.

I am not sure how to resolve this, and make the Validation vanish once it is corrected.  Seeing the warning remain is very confusing for users.

What am I missing?  I attempted to include the Validation rule in the model, on the 'OtherIncidentType' in addition to 'type_other' . . .  and although that changed things slightly - it did not yield the results I expected.